# How to reset the mockrepository object to call the original method after all the calls in mocks.record() are made?

Tags: rhino-mocks

I have a .NET 3.5 Win Form application with three classes login.cs,Main.cs,dBTansaction.cs. I am writing a testcase to for Main.cs which makes calls to dbTransaction.cs. So I mocked to DBTransaction.cs to return diff values for each call and it all works fine. After the testcase is run in my teardown, i close the application for which it calls the login.cs to check if user is allowed to close application. This login.cs also makes call to DBTransaction.cs and since i mocked this class in testcase it throws an exception saying unexpected call.

How do i reset the mock objec to redirect to the original DBTRansactio.cs when called from TearDown.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a unit test for main.cs, then all of its dependencies (login and dbtransaction) should be mocked.  You're already mocking dbtransation.  I suggest you mock out your login as well so you don't have to worry about *any* external dependencies in your tests.